# Simple Post Request in Angular 2 with type or model

Tags: angular, typescript, post, model-view-controller, angular2-forms

right now I am trying to make a simple post request. here is the form

```
<label for="name">Name</label>
<input type="text" id="value" [(ngModel)]="value" />
<input type="button" value="Get Name" (click)="getName(value)" />
```

and here is the the .ts

```
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-home',
    templateUrl: './add-name.component.html'
})

export class FetchNameComponent {
    chosenName: string;
    constructor(
        private http: HttpClient
    )
    {
    }

    getName(value): void {
        this.chosenName = value
        alert(this.chosenName)
        this.http.post("NameItem", this.chosenName).subscribe(result => {
            console.log(result);
        }, error => console.error(error));
    }
}
```

my alert is showing me the correct value so I know that up to this point evertyhing is alright

and here is my controller

```
   [HttpPost]
        public String Post(String chosenName)
        {
            string newName = chosenName + "123";
            return newName;
        }
```

chosenName is always null so something is wrong. I am curious about how to send types and objects into post requests using angular2

if I wanted to send an object through would it look similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming the backend is C# .net. If so, what your api will expect is 'chosenName' in your querystring. so, you post url should be, `/apiUrl/?chosenName="somename"`

So, your post request should look like:

```
this.http.post("/apiUrl/?chosenName=" + this.choosenName).subscribe(result => {
    console.log(result);
}, error => console.error(error));
```

But if you want to post it in data rather than in url, you may have to modify your api. Here is a [good article](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/webapi/parameter-binding-in-web-api)

Then, you can pass more complex objects through post:

```
const data = {chooseName: this.chooseName, anotherValue: "someValue"};
this.http.post("/apiUrl/", data).subscribe(result => {
    console.log(result);
}, error => console.error(error));
```